# is there a way to rebuild /downloader/cache.cfg?

Tags: magento-connect

I have quite a messy installation on hand, that i would like to clean up.

the original installation has been updated and the package information in Magento Connect don't mirror the actual content of the installation. I now want to remove some extensions.

The obsolete extension files that need to be removed are stored in the package.xml file that comes with the extension, so my thought was to put this file into /var/package and remove the extension via Magento Connect.

Problem is, that Magento Connect doesn't recognize *.xml files I put there. I know that the information displayed in MC are stored in /downloader/cache.cfg. When I delete this file, the list of installed packages in MC is empty.

Is there a way to rebuild this list from the *.xml files stored in /var/package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible via the command line:

```
./mage clear-cache
./mage mage-setup .
./mage sync --force
./mage sync-pear --force
```

Comment: almost.      

    `./mage sync --force`

stopps with:

    `sync: Channel 'connect.magentocommerce.com/community' doesn't exist`

Comment: ok, this seems to happen when processing Mage_All_Latest-1.9.0.1.xml: http://screencast.com/t/o6XsDYSHM

Comment: Sounds strange. Did you note the dot after `mage-setup`? You could also try to manually add the channel via `./mage channel-add http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community`. And maybe try to replace the problematic package file with the original one.

Comment: it was a problem in an .xml file of an extension, I tried to simply copy a package.xml file into /var/package which oviously doesn't work this way..

Comment: Yeah, you always have to rename it in order to conform to the naming scheme of all the files.

Comment: I think there is more to it. when installing, the content of the package.xml seems to be changed?

Comment: AFAIK only if you update an extension. Since the version number and a hash of the files is included, it changes with each update.

Comment: i "accidentally" deleted /downloader, restored the folder from fresh mage download and the mentioned procedure does not recognized the installed modules...